# My Image src is showing as a number (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a Shopping Cart using React and I have a *Featured* section on my front page that I want to display five separate images and a title underneath. I have several different components.

FeaturedGamesList.js

```
import vg01 from "../Images/vg-game-01.png";
import vg02 from "../Images/vg-game-03.png";
import vg03 from "../Images/vg-game-05.png";
import vg04 from "../Images/vg-game-07.png";
import vg05 from "../Images/vg-game-02.png";

const FeaturedGamesList = [vg01, vg02, vg03, vg04, vg05];
```

That is just the component that stores all the images.

FeaturedGames.js

```
const FeaturedGames = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "VG 1",
    src: FeaturedGamesList[0],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "VG 2",
    src: FeaturedGamesList[1],
  },
 etc...
];
```

This is the object that has all the stored information that I will need to loop through. I'm not sure if I did the `src` properly but each one is meant to be the path to the image. I tried setting each `src` to `vg01`, `vg02`, etc. but it was saying `not found`. I should also note that all components are in the same folder.

And here is where I'm attempting to loop through the object and have five separate divs, with each div having its own image.

Featured.js

```
const Featured = () => {
  console.log(FeaturedGames);

  return (
    <div>
      {FeaturedGames.map((title, src) => (
        <div className="featured">
          <img key={src} src={src} alt={title} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Everything seems to be working fine because I have the className set to featured which displays a border and five separate divs are showing up, but I can't seem to get the images to show properly. When I inspect the HTML this is what's showing up.

```
<div class="featured"><img src="0" alt="[object Object]"></div>
```

The second div is showing as `src="1"` and etc. Any ideas how to fix this so the images show up properly?

Comment: You're using the index parameter of the `map` callback as `src`. That parameter is the **index** of the element, see [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this

```
const Featured = () => {
  console.log(FeaturedGames);

  return (
    <div>
      {FeaturedGames.map(({title, src}, index) => (
        <div className="featured">
          <img key={src} src={src} alt={title} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

See how [map works](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

```
array.map((array_item, index) => {})
```

Here the first parameter of map method is `array_item` and second parameter is `index`. So when you write like below

```
FeaturedGames.map((title, src) => {})
```

It actually storing each item from the array in the `title` variable and index of the item in the `src` variable that's why when you are using `src` it was giving the index.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this bit:

```js
{FeaturedGames.map((title, src) => (
```

The second parameter of your `.map` callback is your index (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters)

and the first one is the element that's been processed in the array, in your case it's an object and you only need `title` and `src` from it, so you'd do a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so the final result would be as [@moshfiqrony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75220353/5078746) mentioned:

```
const Featured = () => {
  console.log(FeaturedGames);

  return (
    <div>
      {FeaturedGames.map(({title, src}, index) => (
        <div className="featured">
          <img key={src} src={src} alt={title} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```